# Azure asp.net - why the webjob %temp% folder is not the same as the web app %temp% folder?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a webjob that writes some data on the %temp% folder, which maps to d:\local\temp.

When i use the console tool on the azure portal, the data is there, on d:\local\temp.

When i try to access the files on the website (asp.net) the files are not there. But %temp% also maps to d:\local\temp.

Why?

Is there a path that maps to the same location?

The data I write on the local %temp% is a cache of a data stored on azure storage blob. I can re-create the cache if the data on %temp% is lost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main web app and the webjob run in 2 different sandboxed environments on the same VM. They have access to the same `D:\home`, but different `D:\local`.

Keep in mind that `D:\home` and `D:\local` are virtualized paths. They don't really exist on the filesystem. That's why you can run as many sites as you want on the same VM and each will have their own `D:\home` and `D:\local`.

If you want them to share something through the filesystem, you'll have to drop it under `D:\home`